# How is a Ruby Gem usually updated (from developers to my applications)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

We are using the tiny_mce plugin in our applications, utilized through the Ruby Gem.

First question:

The plugin is hosted here https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce/, and there the latest version is listed as 0.1.7 https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce/blob/master/CHANGELOG_PLUGIN.rdoc.  But [as hosted on RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/tiny_mce), the latest version is 0.1.4 (which is from June 2010).

What is the process that will have to happen for the latest version 0.1.7 to become available to my `gem update tiny_mce` command?  Is there a way for me to utilize the Gem from the github source?  Should i just subscribe to the RubyGems.org tiny_mce listing so that i will get notified when it gets updated?

Second question:

This plugin has JavaScript files associated with it, which were populated in my applications with the `script/generate tiny_mce` command.  What is the standard process of upgrading an application to a newer version of a gem that has associated JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using it as a gem, I think the easiest thing to do is to wait on the author to release the new version to RubyGems.  If you can't wait, you can try this manual process to create the gem from source yourself:

http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/gitgem.htm

But it looks like you may be running it as a plugin?  What version of Rails?  Based on the Readme, if you have it installed directly as a plugin, it appears you can just reinstall the plugin:

script/plugin install git://github.com/kete/tiny_mce.git

Just try in a dev environment that you can revert if anything blows up.